# URL-схема для перехода на определенный View Controller

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Мой Xcode проект имеет собственную URL-схему, при вводе которой в строку браузера открывается приложение. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при вводе URL-схемы открывался определенный View Controller? Как это реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтоб этот View Controller открывался в зависимости от того, какая схема?

Comment: Совершенно верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В URL который вы открываете можно задать кучу всяких параметров через стандартные части URL (параметры, путь, хост и т.п.), все как и при запросах к веб-серверам. Все это дело надо распарсить в методе `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` в вашем потомке `UIApplicationDelegate` и в зависимоти от того что именно пришло произвести какие-либо действия в приложении. Как именно вы что-либо закодируете не регламентируется, так что все в ваших руках